# connect remotely with mysql database stored on server using c#.net in visual studio 2008

Tags: c#, mysql

Hello I want to connect remotely with mysql database which is stored on server and I want to display all table names of that database on console how to do that ?

Information about database is like this

```
 server = "50.62.82.40";database = "db_admin"; uid = "db_usr";password = "wowow";
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace ConsoleApplication2
{

    class Program
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            string myConnectionString = "SERVER=50.62.82.40;" +
                            "DATABASE=db_admin;" +
                            "UID=db_usr;" +
                            "PASSWORD=wowow`enter code here`;";

            MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection(myConnectionString);
            MySqlCommand command = connection.CreateCommand();
            command.CommandText = "SHOW TABLES;";
            MySqlDataReader Reader;
            connection.Open();
            Reader = command.ExecuteReader();
            while (Reader.Read())
            {
                string row = "";
                for (int i = 0; i < Reader.FieldCount; i++)
                    row += Reader.GetValue(i).ToString() + ", ";
                Console.WriteLine(row);
            }
            connection.Close();
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```